# calculate books spine size relative to paper type and number of pages (2 sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

I'm new here and a total beginner in Google Sheets/Excel. I have some knowledge in JavaScript and VBScript and how to read a code.

I hope someone can help me with my problem:
I need to automatically calculate the spine size of a book according to the number of pages of the book and the paper type.

- In sheet 1 I have the book titles, number of pages, and paper type of each book.
- In sheet 2 I have manually measured spines according to different paper types and the number of pages.

I really don't have any idea if this is... something easy or a really difficult/complex thing to do?

[This](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G2PCHVzl-Ky1u-_l3N4kcfyDWr2Nr0X8qOXEemSge6E/edit?usp=sharing) is the link to the books.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `vlookup()` and `match()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      C2:C, 
      Sheet2!A3:F, 
      match(D2:D, Sheet2!A2:F2, 0), 
      true 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

This will give the following spine sizes:

| Books | Format | Pages | Paper type | *Spine size* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Shining | 130x200 | 288 | vol 55 | **16** |
| Billy summers | 130x200 | 608 | vol 55 | **33,5** |
| Magic worlds | 145x200 | 208 | offset 70 | **9,5** |
| The Inner voice | 130x200 | 464 | offset 70 | **20,5** |
| On the west front | 106x180 | 464 | vol 60 | **28,5** |
| Traveler world | 130x200 | 368 | vol 60 | **22,5** |
| Dorian Gray | 106x180 | 368 | vol 70 | **26,5** |
| Christine | 130x200 | 288 | vol 70 | **21** |
| The Wonder | 100x130 | 192 | vol 80 | **15** |
| Secrets of life | 137x208 | 128 | vol 80 | **10** |

The formula goes to the last cell of the first data row.

Comment: Automatically flagged as low quality

Comment: thank you very much!